# jQuery animate image swap

Tags: jquery, jquery-effects

I'm looking to have an image swap inside an image gallery in a way that when a user hovers over an image it grows in size and swaps out the image.  At the moment its working but it does a very soft fadeIn and fadeOut effect.  How can I change this so that its a faster transition and the image actually looks like its growing in size?

HTML

```
<li class="carousel-img" 
    data-alt-src="<?php the_sub_field('carousel_image_hover');?>" 
    style="background-image:url( <?php the_sub_field('carousel_image');?> )"
>
```

jQuery

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(e) {
         var bkgd_bl = "";
         jQuery('#carousel a li').hover(function() {

             var bkgd = "url('" + jQuery(this).attr('data-alt-src') + "')";
             bkgd_bl = jQuery(this).css('background-image');

             jQuery(this).stop().fadeOut("1000", function() {
                 jQuery(this).css({
                     "background-image": bkgd,
                     "height": 223,
                     "width": 449 }).fadeIn(1000); //alert(bkgd_bl);
             });
            }, function() {
                jQuery(this).stop().fadeOut("1000", function() {
                    jQuery(this).css({
                        "background-image": bkgd_bl,
                        "height": 172,
                        "width": 265 }).fadeIn(1000);
                });
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

maybe just change

```
fadeIn(1000);
```

to faster? 300? If that's waht You want.. Show some fiddle.

at the very bottom of http://iab.org.pl/ You`ll se logotypes, is that the effect You wanna achieve?

Comment: Not really. The image that its being swapped out for is a larger size. I'd like the user to actually see it grow. The example on the website is doing a zoom in of some sort..

Comment: could You just put what You have into fiddle? I cannot get the idea :/

Comment: the code about is what I have right now and its not what I'd like it to do.  I'm looking for an effect where there is an image swap - but the since the 2nd image is larger, I would like the user to see it expand instead of fade In.

Comment: sooo... what You wanna do is to animate property of background-size, what is currently impossible; You could try animating variable from initial size (100) to destination (f.e. 200) and on each step assigning background-size to the node.

http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/fun-with-jquerys-animate/ heres link for animating variables

background-position:center will also help i assume

Comment: What if I were to change the image instead of being a background image to an image inside a div?

Comment: wohoow, it would be soo much easier. You create container with two images - static and one which is supposed to be growing on hover. Then You add overflow:hidden; to this container you add two absolute positioned images. and You dont need JS at all - look here http://jsfiddle.net/F8S7D/ - ive made demo.

Comment: I really like this solution - it just needs a bit more tweaking..  the image that is coming up on hover is actually larger in size and should push over the image that's next to it.  At the moment its only zooming into it.